# Is it possible to create an APK to install media files, no application

Tags: android, apk

We have a situation that is requiring me to create a stand-alone APK that will install media files only, that can be access by other system software.  On this platform, there are no concerns for file access.  I only need a method for bundling the media files into an APK, so that deployment would be simple

Answer (score 0):

APK stands for [Android Application Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package). There should be at least one activity if you would like to publish it on Google.Play.